# Exchange items in array without temp vars

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Hi I've got follow object:

```
        myList = {
            Items: [
                {
                    ID: 1,
                    Name: "last"
                },
                {
                    ID: 2,
                    Name: "before last"
                },
                {
                    ID: 3,
                    Name: "second"
                }, 
                {
                    ID: 4,
                    Name: "first"
                }
            ]
        };
```

The order in my array is now: 1, 2, 3 and 4.

Now I'd like to exchange the item with ID == 4 with the first one (ID == 1) and the item with the ID == 3 with the second one (ID == 2). Is there a way to do this **without some temp vars**? So that I probably can say, put the item with ID == 4 on the first index and the other would automaticly move down and don't be overwritten? And if there isn't any way without temp vars, how should I do this best with such temp vars?

Thanks and cheers

Comment: Just reverse the array, you want order like 4,3,2,1 from 1,2,3,4

Comment: @Rishi How can I reverse it?

Comment: @Rishi I found it, myList.Items.reverse() - Thanks and cheers.

Comment: Have you ever considered lodash: https://lodash.com/docs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
myList = {
            Items: [
                {
                    ID: 1,
                    Name: "last"
                },
                {
                    ID: 2,
                    Name: "before last"
                },
                {
                    ID: 3,
                    Name: "second"
                }, 
                {
                    ID: 4,
                    Name: "first"
                }
            ]
        };
console.log(myList);

myList = {Items: myList.Items.reverse()};

console.log(myList);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a new array with the elements, you like to exchange.

```
myList.Items = [myList.Items[3], myList.Items[2], myList.Items[1], myList.Items[0]];
```

Or use [`Array#reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse)

> The **`reverse()`** method reverses an array in place. The first array element becomes the last and the last becomes the first.

```
myList.Items.reverse();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
myList.Items = myList.Items.reverse();
```

or

```
<ul ng-repeat="item in myList.Items |  orderBy:'ID':reverse">
```